# configuring synergy with dual monitor server on top of single monitor client

Tags: windows, ubuntu, multiple-monitors, synergy

I'm trying (and failing) to configure synergy with a dual monitor ubuntu synergy server on top of a single monitor Windows client:

```
|-------------------------||-------------------------|
|                         ||                         |
|                         ||                         |
|        primary          ||    secondary            |
|        Ubuntu           ||    Ubuntu               |
|        monitor          ||    monitor              |
|-------------------------||-------------------------|
             |-------------------------|
             |                         |
             |    Windows client       |
             |                         |
             |                         |
             |                         |
             |-------------------------|
```

The problem is that I can only transition between ubuntu and windows from the primary ubuntu monitor and not the secondary - trying to move "down" on the secondary monitor is as if there's nothing there.

I've tried setting up through the "configure interactively" settings (by putting one screen on top of the other), and manually with a synergy.conf as follows:

```
section: screens
 windowsbox:
 ubuntubox:
end
section: links
 windowsbox:
    up(0,50)   = ubuntubox(25,50)
    up(50,100) = ubuntubox(50,75)
 uf8bc127351ab5390f653:
    down(25,50) = windowsbox(0,50)
    down(50,75) = windowsbox(50,100)
end
```

If I do the reverse (make my single monitor windows box the server and dual monitor ubuntu box the client) with the same monitor arrangement, it works great. The main reason I have for wanting the Windows box to be the client is that it's a laptop that's not always there/on - I want my mouse/keyboard to still work on ubuntu even if the windows box is not on.

Anyone have an idea on how to fix this? I'm even open to using a different tool other than synergy if that's what it takes... (if it matters, I'm using Synergy 1.5.1)

Comment: How are your Linux screens configured?  Separate screens, Xinerama, TwinView, Zaphod, etc?  The solution is very different for each possibility.

Comment: Honestly I didn't really configure them - I plugged them in and they just worked. There is an onboard VGA and DisplayPort, so I plugged one monitor into each and they appeared properly in Display settings (System Settings --> Displays through the UI). I'm using Ubuntu 12.04. How can I tell which of those configurations my system decided to use?

Comment: I'm not sure, maybe you can ask on a Ubuntu forum?  You'd expect Xinerama to be the normal method, but if that were true then your Synergy configuration should work as-is.  Can you confirm you have "ubuntubox" listed as the screen name?  Not sure what "uf8bc12...etc" is in the example config you posted.